# Composite Type not found after a table creation

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm struggling with Postgres, I created my DB with some tables and was expecting to find a composite type after the tables' creation with the same name as the table: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html
But I can't find any composite types, at all.

I checked through the command line, PGadmin, but nothing !

What am I missing ?

My question is still on, if i may say. because I'm trying to map in C# my DB so `this.connection.TypeMapper.MapComposite<MyTable>(nameof(MyTable));` should do the trick, but it doesn't find MyTable as a Type. When I'm listing all the types, I can't find MyTable

Comment: Creating a table will most certainly [create a row in pg_type](https://dbfiddle.uk/P9RFUHh2)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found my composite type by adding the parameter `LoadTableComposites=True` to my connection string

Comment: The answer I was looking for.